# .net mvc and SEO

Tags: asp.net-mvc, seo

so I just migrated a bunch of my old web sites to .net mvc and turned them loose on the net last week.

I optimized them as best I know how for SEO but I'm noticing that NONE (not a single one!) of my sub pages is being displayed on google...only my home pages.

I created controllers for the products to try and give them plugs for each page.

ex:
http://www.mywidgets.com/widget_to_make_coffee/coffee_making_widgets

ironically, google is still showing some of my sub-pages from the old site, which I have redirecting to the new, but I fear that when it fully updates its index, I will lose that placement and not gain the placement from my new stuff as it's no-where to be found...

is this bad practice?  Should I have structured everything off of the home controller?

Comment: Are you pages available to Google when you visit them from outside your firewall? Do they return an HTTP 200 code?

What happens when somebody visits the old link? Are you redirecting them to the new URL? Is the redirection temporary or permanent?

Comment: yes I can hit all the links directly....the redirect is permanent from the old links to the home page of my sites.

Comment: Your comment seems to say it all - "The redirect is permanent from the old links to the HOME PAGE of my new site" can't they redirect to the new URL?

Comment: @PeterLaCombJr. yes you're right on that front, but I'm surprised that the spiders aren't indexing my other pages.  I'm not so concerned about the redirects to my home page.  But when a spider crawls my site and indexes all of the pages, it should (in theory) also add some of the other sub pages as possible "hits" when someone searches...and my initial question is why am I not seeing ANY of those sub pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I have structured everything off of the home controller?

No. Something else it's going on.

One of the advantages of ASP.NET MVC is that you can de-couple your routes (URLs) from the logic of your code (models/views/controllers)

Comment: ok, just wanted to make sure that NOT having an extension (ie .html) wasn't hurting my placement.  I guess it's back to the drawing board then to find out why none of my sub pages are being listed...

Comment: @ChristopherJohnson:  I am not an SEO expert but I believe that the redirect code (301 vs a 302) can have a big impact when doing redirects and Google search rankings.  You might want to research that a little more and ensure you are returning the proper redirect response when Google comes knocking.  http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/

Answer (score 0):

The only important thing is that you have something at the old urls passing a 301 redirect to the new urls. Google will fix itself pretty quickly after that.

Depending on how many incoming links you've got, you might end up keeping the redirector up permanently.